# Comparação de String em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com uma dúvida na comparação de string utilizando Javascript / jQuery.

Eu quero que se a cidade no `input id="cidade"` **não for** `Goiânia` ou `Aparecida de Goiânia` exiba o 
`alert`.

Porém mesmo quando a cidade é `Goiânia` o `alert` está sendo exibido. Conforme o exemplo abaixo em que já defini o valor manualmente como `Goiânia` para testes.

```js
$( "#botao" ).click(function() {
 var verificarcidade = $('#cidade').val();
 if (verificarcidade != 'Goiânia' || verificarcidade != 'Aparecida de Goiânia' ){
  alert('Parar');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="cidade" type="text" value="Goiânia" required />
<a href="#" id="botao" role="button">Calcular</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que alterar o `||` para `&&`. Da forma que está, a segunda condição é verdadeira, retornando o `alert`. Para não entrar no `alert`, ambas as condições devem ser falsas (`&&`), e não uma **ou** outra (`||`).

```js
$( "#botao" ).click(function() {
 var verificarcidade = $('#cidade').val();
 if (verificarcidade != 'Goiânia' && verificarcidade != 'Aparecida de Goiânia' ){
  alert('Parar');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cidade" type="text" value="Goiânia" required />
<a href="#" id="botao" role="button">Calcular</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#botao").click(function() {
    var verificarcidade = $('#cidade').val();
    console.log(verificarcidade);
    if (verificarcidade.replace('â','a').toLowerCase() != 'goiania' && verificarcidade.replace('â','a').toLowerCase() != 'aparecida de goiania' ){
        alert('Parar');
    }
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="cidade" type="text" value="Goiânia" required />
<a href="#" id="botao" role="button">Calcular</a>
```